# SMS Retriever API - how to programmatically get SMSs?

Tags: java, android, android-sms

I want to implement sms OTP receiver in my android project which is totally in java not kotlin. Please can anyone help me to do this thing in android using java language?

I was tried kotlin code in my android project but my UI functionalities is based on java code, please help me.

Comment: Did you mean SMS Retirever? Please read this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

Comment: yes but i don't have any idea how to implement it in pure java without any kotlin code

Comment: The link which is shared by @StanleyKou is completely written in java not kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for Java

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //this will update the UI with message
            SmsActivity inst = SmsActivity.instance();
            inst.updateList(smsMessageStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Try using something like this for Kotlin

```
class SmsBroadcastReceiver:BroadcastReceiver() {
  fun onReceive(context:Context, intent:Intent) {
    val intentExtras = intent.getExtras()
    if (intentExtras != null)
    {
      val sms = intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE) as Array<Any>
      val smsMessageStr = ""
      for (i in sms.indices)
      {
        val smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray)
        val smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString()
        val address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress()
        smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n"
        smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n"
      }
      Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      //this will update the UI with message
      val inst = SmsActivity.instance()
      inst.updateList(smsMessageStr)
    }
  }
  companion object {
    val SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus"
  }
}
```